# Unknown column 'pizza' in 'field list' помогите решить

Tags: php

У меня возникла проблема при изучение работы с базами данных.Проблема в том,что я должен вводить заказ (или что-то другое) и это записывалось в бд.Но получается вот такая проблема "Unknown column 'pizza' in 'field list'".Спасибо.

Вот код

```html
<div id="login-form">
  <h1>order</h1>


  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name">

    <input type="submit" value="отправить">

  </form>


</div>
```

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name']) && (!empty($_POST['name']))) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "db";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE `main` SET `order`=$name WHERE id = 1";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
} 
else {

    $name = 'not ok';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном примере ваш текст попадает в запрос без апострофов и расценивается как имя поля. Соответственно запрос должен выглядеть так

```
$sql = "UPDATE `main` SET `order` = '$name' WHERE id = 1";
```

Замечу, что такой метод подстановки небезопасен и годится разве что только для начального обучения

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду использовать pdo надо?

Comment: Да. Или самому эскейпить все приходящие значения